# Parameter Value

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2013

```
SELECT ID, AppID, Description, Min([Transaction Date]) AS TransactionDate
FROM AppProsHist
WHERE [Description]='Non-Final Rejection'
GROUP BY ID, AppID, Description
ORDER BY TransactionDate DESC
```

I keep receiving a Parameter Value box for "TransactionDate." Does anyone know how I make that go away?

Comment: do you actually have a field called "Transaction Date" in your base table? (with a space)

Comment: yes I do, but The Min() isn't actually doing what I hoped it would do. However, when I take away that portion of the code everything breaks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TransactionDate` is an alias for the field expression `Min([Transaction Date])`

Access does not accept an alias in the `ORDER BY`.  Either of these 2 alternatives should work ...

```sql
ORDER BY Min([Transaction Date]) DESC
ORDER BY 4 DESC
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how to make it so that only the first/earliest date is picked? I was under the impression that the Min() did that, although it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: `Min([Transaction Date])` should give you the first/earliest/oldest date for each combination of `ID`, `AppID`, and `Description`.  (Actually, all the result set rows will have same `Description` because of the `WHERE` clause ... but I don't see why that matters here.)  If that is *not* what you're seeing, please show us a data sample and what you get from the query based on that data sample.

Comment: Or did you want the query to return only one row, with the earliest date which satisfies the `WHERE [Description]='Non-Final Rejection'` constraint?

Comment: That sounds right, I just need the Transaction to come back with the earliest date.

Comment: so lets say the AppID is "98" and the ID's are 12,14,16, (different numbers) and there are three dates. The query is returning each date, in seemingly no order. I want just the earliest date and for the AppID of "98"

Comment: No, let's say the question is about making the "parameter value" issue go away (it is!)  After I showed you how to make it go away, you discovered the query does not give you what you want.  That is a new and different question; make it so.